# Auto adjust images of variable height

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I have a list of images (thumbnails), displayed as a gallery. These images have fixed width and variable height.

But page look wired because of variable height of images

http://www.geoffreywarnerstudio.com/live-edge-2

Is there any possible solution using jQuery or PHP to make this look good, i.e. automatically adjust images 4 in a row?

---

**Update:**

I have created a jsFiddle to make it easier to test the code: http://jsfiddle.net/alokjain_lucky/vHVcP/

Please i do not want images to be cropped, or stretched to make them equal height.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created following solution for my requirement:
http://jsfiddle.net/alokjain_lucky/vHVcP/

Answer (score 0):

If you are not bother about compressing the image height on thumbnails simply add a fixed height to the thumbnails.

Eg: Add `height: 100px;` to `ul.small-thumb-3 li img` in style.css

Comment: I don't want to add a fixed height.

Comment: @AlokJain then add a fixed height to the box they are in then let the images float in the middle

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to CSS, here's a [Wordpress plugin](http://ditio.net/2010/01/02/jquery-image-resize-plugin/) that essentially does it for you.

Comment: This plugin is used to resize images, not to adjust them in rows.

Answer (score 0):

Useful Link for creating same size of thumbnails:

http://www.plus2net.com/php_tutorial/php_thumbnail.php

Answer (score 0):

You could try to get the height of each thumbnail, put them in array and then uset natsort or similar to sort them from highest to lowest or other way around. That is IF the order does not matter. This way you would get similarly sized images next to each other and it would look slighly better.

To get the image size:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php

Also you say "Please i do not want images to be cropped, or stretched to make them equal height." So  there's pretty much no other way if images can't be changed in any way..

EDIT: Here's slightly better looking version: http://jsfiddle.net/vHVcP/10/

Answer (score 0):

Put a border around the images, then dynamically center the images within the border.

http://jsfiddle.net/saluce/vHVcP/19/